# How to get the latest updated time of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, caching

I have a small table in DB of mysql on which "select" query will be very frequent but "update" or "insert into" infrequent, and I want to cache the table in memory.

When "select" comes, it check the updated time of the table first. if the time is the same with the last one, the cache will be valid and it can give the query result from the cache directly.

So how can I get the latest updated time of a table in mysql?

Or any other solution？

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way. If you want to keep track of update times, you have to do it in your own code.

Comment: yes, I did it in my own code.

Comment: What you can do is have a `last_updated` column that has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you can use `SELECT MAX(last_updated) FROM tablename`